# Recognize selected text in start and end of text with regex c#

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have text that starts with `(parag1 level="All")` as start tag and end with `(/parag1)` as end tag, and between them is text.

How can I with regex in C# check that the user selected text with start tag or end tags?
I use parentheses for tags: `(tag)text(/tag)`

**Example:**

```
(Parag1 level="All")
This is my string1. This is my string2. This is my string3.
(/Parag1)
```

**The user may select:**

```
(Parag1 level="All")
This is my
```

Or

```
level="All")
This is my
```

Or (this one is does not have the start tag)

```
is my string1
```

Or (this one has the start tag with l") and end tag with (   )

```
l")
This is my string1. This is my string2. This is my string3.
(
```

**I want to check:**

- Does it start with "start tag" or part of "start tag"?
  Selected text 1 and 2,4 is ok, but 3 is no.
- Does it end with "end tag" or part of "end tag"?
  Selected text 1,2,3 is no, but 4 is ok.

---

How can i change my regex patern that include all below text.
pattern :

```
(<Parag)\d+\s(Level=")\w+(">)
```

text :

```
<Parag1 Level="all">

<Parag2 Level="Total">

Parag3 Level="all">

arag4 Level="all">

rag5 Level="all">

ag6 Level="all">

g7 Level="all">

8 Level="all">

 Level="all">

Level="all">

evel="all">

vel="all">

el="all">

l="all">

="all">

="all">

"all">

all">

ll">

l">

">

>
```

Change regex pattern c#

Comment: Can the tags be nested? Should you support any possible text, or do you know it only has one tag? Do you have parentheses in your text, which are not tags?

Comment: [<Parag]*?[\d]*?[\s][Level="]*?[\w]*?["]?(>) is correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this isn't a `RegEx` solution as you requested, but here's an outside the box idea.  Since your example text has some XML-like qualities, have you considered replacing the `(` and `)` with `<` and `>` and parsing it with an XML parser?

To use this solution though, your text could not have any parenthesis other than the tags, and you would have to replace any illegal characters with their respective escape sequences.

One other issue you would have to deal with is a root-level tag.  If one does not exist, you would have to wrap your original string in one:

```
String data = // your string here with all opening and closed tags    
data = "<root>" + data + "</root>"  //if your data does not have a root tag, if it does, you can omit this
data = data.Replace('(', '<').Replace(')', '>');


XElement element = XElement.Parse(data);
```

Comment: My data text is "level="All") This is my". please get me parag number !?

Comment: @a_ahmadi how does the user select the text as you are referring?  XML is not flexible when it comes to incomplete data, so it is not going to parse unless it includes the start and end tags.  The purpose of my answer was to try to point you in an easier direction from the start.

Answer (score 1):

You have to solve your problem in 2 steps:
1) look for the start/end blocks with a regex, with multiline option set.
2) look for your text with a regular String.IndexOf

From 1 you know which are the positions of start/end tags.

For example:

```
          1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8
012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
(parag1 level="all")This is my string1. This is my...
```

This start block goes from position 0 to 19. You can get this info from the regex matches

If the user provides this string:

```
level="all")This is my
```

the indexOf for this string is 8. And the end position is 8 + string.Length = 19. But probably you won't need to to this call to indexOf, as I suppose you have the start and end positions of the user's selection.

Then you simply have to check is start position is between begin/end of your block. In this case 8 is between 0 and 19, so the user selected part of the start tag.

Apply this technique for the whole text and for start and end blocks, and you get it.

EDIT: regex for finding start/end tags:

```
(?<pStart>\(parag(?<no>\d+).*?\))

(?<pEnd>\(/parag(?<no>\d+)\))
```

When you run `Regex.Matches` you get a collection of matches, and you can get their start/end positions, and even the paragraph number. This groups are captured as pStart+no (1st regex), and pEnd+no (2nd regex).

Then you can find the paragrpah number and start and end position like this:

```
Regex re = new Regex(@"(?<pStart>\(parag(?<no>\d+).*?\))", RegexOptions.Multiline);
MatchCollection matches = re.Matches(s2);
```

You get this infor for each match:

```
matches[0].Groups["pStart"]; // captured text
matches[0].Groups["pStart"].Index; // start position
matches[0].Groups["pStart"].Length; // end position, if addes to start position
matches[0].Groups["no"]; // paragraph number, which can be parsed to int
```

Comment: This works as long as tags are not nested. The OP never said they could be, of course...

Comment: Thank's from you. My text is include parag1 ... parag999 ... blocks. Similar xml file. And I don't know start and end positions of tags. Too, level value is all,mytext1,mytext2,...

Comment: I've added info to let you find the tags and there positions and numbers in the text. Complete solution to your problem.